# Using service principals / apps for OAuth2 authentication within Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

We aim to collect data from the Azure Management APIs.  These APIs provide information on the resources we have running in Azure, the consumed budget, etc [(example)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list).  Following our design choices, we prefer to exclusively use Azure Data Factory to make the HTTP requests and store the data into our data lakes.  This is fairly obvious, using the REST linked service. **However, we struggle to correctly set up the OAuth2 authentication dance with this method.**

1. Our first idea was to store the token and the refresh token within the Azure Key Vault.  A series of HTTP requests within the pipeline would then test whether the token is still valid or otherwise use the refresh token to get a new token.  The downside to this approach is that the token within the Azure Key Vault is never updated, when needed, and that the logic becomes more complex.
2. Alternatively, we were trying to set up the authorization through combination of a registered app and service principal to our Azure AD account.  The REST linked service within Data Factory can be created with a service principal, which would then handle most of the information of the scope and consent.  The service principal is also accompanied with a Azure app, which would hold the token etc.  Unfortunately, we are unable to make this setup function correctly.

Questions we have:

- Can we actually use a service principal / app to store our OAuth2 tokens?  If so, will these be automatically refreshed within our app?
- How do we assign the correct privileges / authorizations to our app that it can use this (external) API?
- Is the additional logic with HTTP calls within Azure Data Factory pipeline needed to update the tokens or can these apps / service principals handle this?

Thank you for your time and help!

[image: View of the REST linked service within Azure Data Factory]

[image: View of a registered app within Azure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to store the tokens in the keyvault, because they will expire.

In your case, two options for you to use.

1. Use service principal to auth
2. Use managed identity to auth(best practice)

### Steps to use service principal to auth:

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.To call the Azure REST API e.g. [`Resources - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) you mentioned, your service principal needs the RBAC role in your subscription.

Navigate to the Azure portal -> `Subscription` -> add your service principal as a `Contributor`/`Owner` role in the subscription like below.

[image]

4.In the linked service, configure it like below, fix them with the values got from step 2.

[image]

Don't forget to replace the `{subscriptionId}` in the `Base URL`.

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2020-06-01`

5.Test the linked service with a copy activity, it works fine.

[image]

### Steps to use managed identity to auth:

1.Make sure your data factory has [enabled the MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#generate-managed-identity), if you create it in the portal or powershell, MSI will be enabled automatically, don't worry about that.

2.Navigate to the Subsctiption in the portal, add the role to the MSI like step 3 in `Steps to use service principal to auth`, just search for your ADF name in the bar, the MSI is essentially a service principal with the same name of your ADF, which is managed by azure.

3.Then in the linked service, just change it like below.

[image]

---

At last, answer your questions.

> Can we actually use a service principal / app to store our OAuth2 tokens? If so, will these be automatically refreshed within our app?

As I mentioned, it is not a good idea, just use the service principal/MSI to auth like the steps above.

> How do we assign the correct privileges / authorizations to our app that it can use this (external) API?

To use the Azure REST API, just assign the RBAC roles like above, specify the correct `AAD resource` e.g. `https://management.azure.com` in this case.

> Is the additional logic with HTTP calls within Azure Data Factory pipeline needed to update the tokens or can these apps / service principals handle this?

No need to do other steps, when you use the configuration above, essentially it will use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token in the background for you automatically, then use the token to call the API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  The MSI approach works like a charm!

Comment: I assume you cannot use the MSI approach for external APIs (external being outside Azure / MSFT).  Could you hint on how to set up such a configuration?  Would you then use a registered application?

Comment: @bramb Well, if the APIs are outside of Azure(not secured by azure ad), both auth of MSI and service principal will not work, they just work for APIs secured by azure ad, to use which way to auth, it depends on how the APIs secured by.

Comment: Sounds clear to me!  Looking further, it seems that the MSI is not supported for all services / the APIs of these services, such as Azure Cost Management and Azure DevOps.  Would you then use the service principal method?  

Looking specifically at the Cost Management side, can you assign the service principal as an Enterprise Admin or would you need to give it cost management reader to all subscriptions / management groups?

Comment: @bramb Basically, you can use MSI to auth with any services/APIs that service principal can, MSI is essentially a service principal managed by azure, but sometimes the steps are complicated. For the RBAC roles, all of them can be assigned to the MSI/service principal, for the scope of the assignement, it depends your API query scope, if you just call the API against a resource group, then in the group scope, it is enough, if against the subscription, then you need assign the role at the subscription scope.

Comment: So for calling the API below, the RBAC role "cost management reader" on the subscription should suffice for my managed identity?  API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/balances/getbybillingaccount

Comment: @bramb Basically yes.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for all the information.  It seems that I am starting to understand this then.  I have one final question.  Why is the managed identity preferred over the service principal?  Would it not make sense to use a service principal, so you can reuse it over various data factories / services?

Comment: @bramb 1.Because MSI is just available in azure environment, and no secrets, will not have security issue. 2.Yes, but you can use user-assigned identity instead of system-assigned identity in some supported services(ADF not support the user-assigned one)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities